# How to input scalar (non-image) values to CNNs?

Tags: input, conv-neural-network, scalar

The classification task is based on a image and a scalar value.

If I encoded the scalar value as image pixels with that value (or a normalized version of the same) and append it as another layer in the input image, I would be wasting convolutional computation cycles over the encoding to get this information into the network.

On the other hand, I can send this as another neuron to the layer where flattening of conved feature maps occurs. Another option would be adding just before the output layer. *(But how do I implement such a network in Keras or tensorflow?)*

**Which is the best method to send in scalar values?**

PS: Although this question is not specific to any framework, Keras examples would be great in a way that they are simple enough for most people to understand... Links to blogs addressing the same are welcome too.

Answer (score 2):

See this question and answer on the Cross Validated site: [Combining image and scalar inputs into a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299322/combining-image-and-scalar-inputs-into-a-neural-network?rq=1)
In addition to the "bias" method suggested in the paper mentioned there(when the scalar is being used as a bias to some convolution layer), and the other option suggested in the answer to append the scalar to some flattened layer, you can also use an inner product (fully connected, "Dense" in Keras) layer to find the connectivity pattern between the ND input to the scalar.